# Alignment of objects in the image and finding the angle of rotation

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, deep-learning

I an trying to align the green rectangle in the image below to be aligned perfectly straight.
[Meter reading image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BTvo.jpg)
This image is very comfortable i.e. straight, but the image will be tilted far more than this
[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gXGw.png)

The solutions I tried:

1. Trying to find lines in the image and then finding the rotation angle: but it failed as it took wrong line and rotated image in the wrong direction.
2. masked the green part of the image and then tried to find Contours and then the rotation angle but was not able to find anything.
   please suggest some solution?

Comment: what's the source of the second image, that "presentation"? -- "not able to find anything" please demonstrate that. please take the [tour] and review [ask] and [mre]

Comment: What is the method currently used in your slides ?

Comment: Try to do an inrange to isolate only the green screen, after that you can use 
(center(x, y), (width, height), angle of rotation) = cv2.minAreaRect(points) to get the area. Check here https://theailearner.com/tag/angle-of-rotation-by-cv2-minarearect/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).